# Does a short combat or casting one spell interrupt a Long Rest?

Tags: dnd-5e, combat, spellcasting, rests

*D&D Basic Rules* v0.1 says on page 67 that a long rest is interrupted by "at least 1 hour of walking, fighting, casting spells". So does that mean that 59 minutes of combat doesn't interrupt the long rest? Or does any combat or spellcasting count as enough interruption to restart the rest?

Comment: Related: [Long rests can be interrupted for up to 1 hour without having to restart the rest; is this limit per-rest or per-interruption?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/147506/33569)

Answer (score 66, accepted):

## A long rest is interrupted by giving up on it

The text is ambiguous, but *1 hour* is meant to apply to the whole period of strenuous activity, while the list is there to define what types of activities could make up that strenuous activity period. The intention is that the rest has to be started over not just for any interruption, but for those unusual times when the party simply gives up on resting.

Mike Mearls clarified this on twitter:

> **The Seven-Sided Die** @sevensideddie [9:30 AM - 9 July 2014](https://twitter.com/sevensideddie/status/486910248960028674)
>   .@mikemearls How are Long Rest interruptions meant to work? The land is in confusion & dismay! [http://forum.rpg.net/showthread.php…](http://forum.rpg.net/showthread.php?730649-5e-So-if-a-long-rest-is-interrupted-you-start-all-over) [https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/42123…](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/42123/does-a-short-combat-or-casting-one-spell-interrupt-a-long-rest)
>
> ---
>
> **Mike Mearls** @mikemearls [10:01 AM - 10 July 2014](https://twitter.com/mikemearls/status/487280500902342656)
>   @sevensideddie interruption needs to be a full hour. Testers: "We rest 7 hours, a kobold knocks on the door, and now we have to start over?
>
> ---
>
> **The Seven-Sided Die** @sevensideddie [10:04 AM - 10 July 2014](https://twitter.com/sevensideddie/status/487281158695055360)
>   .@mikemearls Oh. But that means combat will never interrupt rest, since a 600-round combat is unheard of. Why list it at all then?
>
> ---
>
> **Mike Mearls** @mikemearls [10:05 AM - 10 July 2014](https://twitter.com/mikemearls/status/487281560312217602)
>   @sevensideddie there could be cases where it's valid - fight starts, now you need to leave the dungeon
>
> ---
>
> **The Seven-Sided Die** @sevensideddie [10:07 AM - 10 July 2014](https://twitter.com/sevensideddie/status/487282065662959616)
>   @mikemearls Ah, so it’s meant to be fairly rare, more “we’ve given up resting for now,” not just attacks on the camp.
>
> ---
>
> **Mike Mearls** @mikemearls [10:08 AM - 10 July 2014](https://twitter.com/mikemearls/status/487282167198670849)
>   @sevensideddie exactly

Comment: It's worth noting that Mearls' tweets are not official rulings... Also, while also not an official ruling, [Jeremy Crawford concurs](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/764150520646742016): "Any amount of fighting breaks a short rest. A long rest can withstand an interruption of up to 1 hour."

Comment: Mike mearls are not worth anything as far as rule interpretation goes.  he's just a guy. These tweets are worth nothing more than some forum answers.

Comment: @KilrathiSly Five years ago that wasn’t the case. I’m not sure there’s any edits I can usefully make here to address your comment. What do you have in mind?